# "Extra \fi" error when defining mutually exclusive package options with conditionals

Tags: conditionals, package-writing, package-options

I have been trying to create a package, which loads the `babel` package and sets the language with an option. I've been getting strange errors when trying to define mutually exclusive package options, so as to prevent `babel` options conflict. I've put together a `MWE`. Here is the `failedpackage.sty` file :

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{failedpackage}

\newif\ifbabel@french
\newif\ifbabel@english
\newif\ifbabel@german

%% Option zone
\DeclareOption{french}{\babel@frenchtrue\babel@englishfalse\babel@germanfalse}
\DeclareOption{english}{\babel@frenchfalse\babel@englishtrue\babel@germanfalse}
\DeclareOption{german}{\babel@frenchfalse\babel@englishfalse\babel@germantrue}

\ExecuteOptions{french}

\ProcessOptions
%% end of Option zone


\ifbabel@frenchtrue
    \RequirePackage[french]{babel}
\fi
\ifbabel@englishtrue
    \RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\fi
\ifbabel@germantrue
    \RequirePackage[german]{babel}
\fi


\endinput
```

Here is the `.tex` file to compile :

```
\documentclass[report]

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{failedpackage}

\begin{document}

    Bonjour TeX.StackExchange !

\end{document}
```

And here is the .log document : http://paf.im/8a8tc

Well I guess the problem is caused by the fact that the compiler treats the conditional statements (e.g. `\ifbabel@englishtrue`) as undefined, but they have been defined right at the beginning of the `.sty`!

I don't understand.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: No, the error is `\documentclass[report]` -- it must read `\documentclass{report}` and the `\ifbabel@....` conditionals must go without `true`

Comment: there is `\RequirePackageWithOptions` command  `always loads the required package with exactly the same option list as
that being used by the current class or package`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you, I couldn't understand why some errors showed up in the mwe but not in other documents. Besides, the second part of your comment was the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove the suffix `true` from the `\ifbabel@....` queries!
   You must use `\ifbabel@french` etc for the query, but `\babel@frenchtrue` or `\babel@frenchfalse` to set the state of the 'variable'.
2. Change `\documentclass[report]` to `\documentclass{report}`

---

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{failedpackage}

\newif\ifbabel@french
\newif\ifbabel@english
\newif\ifbabel@german

%% Option zone
\DeclareOption{french}{\babel@frenchtrue\babel@englishfalse\babel@germanfalse}
\DeclareOption{english}{\babel@frenchfalse\babel@englishtrue\babel@germanfalse}
\DeclareOption{german}{\babel@frenchfalse\babel@englishfalse\babel@germantrue}

\ExecuteOptions{french}

\ProcessOptions
%% end of Option zone


\ifbabel@french
\RequirePackage[french]{babel}
\fi

\ifbabel@english
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\fi
\ifbabel@german
\RequirePackage[german]{babel}
\fi


\endinput
```

Main.tex

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     %

\usepackage{failedpackage}

\begin{document}

Bonjour TeX.StackExchange !

\end{document}
```